# What does fifth column of feColorMatrix stands for exactly

Tags: svg, svg-filters

In mozilla's doc for [feColorMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix) it is stated that

> The  SVG filter element changes colors based on a
>   transformation matrix. Every pixel's color value (represented by an
>   [R,G,B,A] vector) is matrix multiplied to create a new color.

However in `feColorMatrix` there are 5 columns, not 4. 
In an excellent [article](https://alistapart.com/article/finessing-fecolormatrix) that can be considered as a classical reference it is stated that:

> The matrix here is actually calculating a final RGBA value in its
>   rows, giving each RGBA channel its own RGBA channel. The last number
>   is a multiplier.

But that does not explain a lot. As far as I understand, since after applying filter we basically modify exactly R, G, B and A channels and nothing else there's no need in this additional parameter. Indirectly there's an evidence for that in the article itself - all numerous examples of feColorMatrix-based filters provided - all have zeroes as fifth component. Also, why it's a multiplier?

In another famous [article](https://css-tricks.com/color-filters-can-turn-your-gray-skies-blue/) it is stated that:

> For the other rows, you are creating each of the rgba output values as
>   the sum of the rgba input values multiplied by the corresponding
>   matrix value, plus a constant.

Calling it a constant added makes more sense than calling it a multiplier, however it's still unclear **what does fifth component in feColor matrix stands for and what is unachievable without it**  - so that would be my question.

My last hope was the w3c reference but it's [surprisingly vague](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) as well.

Comment: I'm not as well-versed in `feColorMatrix` as I'd like (especially since I use it!) but my understanding is that the output is a function of `rR + gG + bB + aA + c` - the last value is a constant addition.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol filter is a function from RGBA to RGBA, even if it is in a matrix form that that basically means that having 4x4 matrix will make it possible to get any value you need - so there's no value you won't be able to obtain without fifth column - at least as far as I understand. This can serve two purposes: 1) it just make some common-case computations easier 2) this constants still have a meaning, in other words every color has additional characteristic apart from rgba channels.

Comment: @shabunc if RGBA = transparent black i.e. 0, 0, 0, 0 how are you going to make it anything other than transparent black without a 5th value to provide a constant addition? Anyway the whole matrix multiplication is [in the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement)

Comment: @RobertLongson good point! it's about black color I guess.  Also the link you've provided is exactly the link I've provided in my question.

Comment: You may find this pen useful: [SVG feColorMatrix](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/ENRZGO)  You may edit the values for the feColorMatrix to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification is clear although you do need to understand matrix math. The fifth column is a fixed offset. It's useful because if you want to add a specific amount of R/G/B/A to your output, that column is the only way to do it. Or if you want to recolor something to a specific color, that's also the way to do it.

For example - if you have multiple opaque colors in your input, but you want to recolor everything to rgba(255,51,0,1) then this is the matrix you would use.

0 0 0 0 1.0

0 0 0 0 0.2

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0

aka

```
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0.5   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 0"/>
```

Try out these sliders for yourself:
https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/qJCDk